# Issue with html tags when retrieving from firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

That is the output I get when I run the code:

```
[19:01:06] User: <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" >http://www.google.com </a>
```

It does not create the link it only displays the a href tag.

This is what makes the link:

```
function linkify(inputText) {
var replacedText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2, replacePattern3;

//URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

//URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');

return replacedText;
```

}

So in the tutorial chat box I sent the text to firebase list such:

```
text=linkify(text);
    myDataRef.push({timestamp: timestamp, name: name, text: text, emote: emote});
```

And this is what the display part looks like:

```
function displayChatMessage(timestamp, name, text, emote) {

        $('<div/>').text('['+timestamp+'] ').append($('<name/>').text(name+': ')).append($('<em/>').text(text)).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
}
$('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
```

};

I have tried to insert other html tags but that wont work either.
The entire code is just based on the tutorial chat and worked from there.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's .text() escapes HTML so that it shows up as text rather than being rendered as HTML.  The chat example uses this intentionally, to avoid [HTML Script Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#HTML-script_injection_.28cross-site_scripting.29).  You could "fix" your code by changing the render code to:

```
$('<div/>').text('['+timestamp+'] ').append($('<name/>').text(name+': ')).append($('<em/>').html(text)).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
```

Note the use of .html(text) instead of .text(text).  **BUT THIS IS NOT SECURE.**  Now, anybody using the chat can type a message with `<script src="http://mysite.com/my-malicious-javascript.js"></script>` as a chat message and everybody else will run that javascript.

Perhaps this jQuery plugin might be a better solution: https://github.com/uudashr/jquery-linkify  (i.e. do the linkification on the receiving side in a presumably safe manner (though I haven't looked at the code).

Comment: Thank you. I will give the Jquery a try first, prefer not to make it less secure then it has to be.